# Looking for Inneroffice Access Tool, Workstation to Workstation

Tags: remote-desktop, display, workstation

This may be a simple question to answer, and I apologize if it's a duplicate.  I looked through the suggestions and nothing jumped out at me as the right answer, so here goes:

My office has several workstations, Macs and Windows boxes.  We do have a firewall and a VPN solution, so getting in to the network from outside is easy.  Likewise, we use GoToMeeting for demos and when we help our customers with their issues.  But we have one workstation that has certain testing tools on it, and instead of walking across the office to this machine, I'd like to access it from my desk (and monitor it).  I will need to open a command line and run commands.

I could start a GoToMeeting and do it this way, but that seems overkill and clunky.  Is there a simpler tool that allows pseudo-remote access within the same office/network for this kind of access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally (like ChrisF already mentioned) I'd suggest remote desktop (RDP).  But I get the impression in this case that you don't want to actually log in to this machine: someone might be using it, or there may be a monitoring tool running that you don't want to interrupt.  I'm also unsure if there's a good rdp client for mac.

With those limitations in mind, you should consider a vnc program like ultravnc or tightvnc.  Those should let you view the current desktop on the machine without interrupting anything and optionally let you interact with the desktop.

Answer (score 2):

To go from one Windows machine to another you could use [Remote Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsXp/using/mobility/getstarted/Remoteintro.mspx). This should be OK if both machines are behind the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

If the box is a newer MAC there VNC server built into the OS. You just have to enable it.